# React Native IOS build failed, linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, react-native, linker, command, build-error

I'm using Xcode 12.4 on Catalina 10.15.7 intel based chip. I created a sample react native project with this 'https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup' and it build and ran perfectly.
Now after further working on the project I installed react native navigation and stack navigator and styled components and vector icon dependencies. Now I run into this issue. Plz help me to resolve this. Thanks.

**error on Xcode build**

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/ahyanawaz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store-bekhqxqflgsqtyheijdxkrbwrksk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket'
ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `npm install` or `yarn` then `cd ios && pod install`